# Get the word from a WordNet synset

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, wordnet

Given a synset like this:

```
Synset("pascal_celery.n.01")
```

I want to get the word(s) it represents:

```
"pascal celery"
```

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
synset.name().split(".")[0]
```

but this doesn't convert underscores into spaces.

Is there an inbuilt way of doing this?

Comment: You could of course do `.replace("_"," ")` on the string; I don't know if nltk has a built-in way of doing it.

Comment: @L3viathan Indeed, that's what I've decided to do. It just seemed like the kind of thing there should be a function for already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [source code of the `Synset` class](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.html#Synset) there is no method to return exactly what you want.

You will probably have to rely on plain old Python `replace`:

```
synset.name().split(".")[0].replace('_',' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the party here, but for posterity, I think you're looking for the `.lemmas()` and `.lemma_names()` methods on synsets.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
dog = wn.synsets('dog')[0]
dog.lemma_names()

>>>['dog', 'domestic_dog', 'Canis_familiaris']
```

From there, you can replace underscores with spaces, and you'll get what you need.